# Invalidating sessions on password change - Sailsjs

Tags: sails.js, session-state, login-control

How do I invalidate a particular user's active sessions when his/her password is changed?

Sails doesn't provide access to sessions globally and each session can be accessed only via the `request` object in a controller, so I can't find a way to access all the active sessions of a particular user.

I could query the `sessions` collection directly if I do not serialize the sessions, since I'm using mongo as a session store, but I can't find a way to access the mongo adapter to perform a query.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for performing your mongo query:

1. `npm install mongodb` and just use it to manually access what you need (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)
2. Create a "dumb" Model (just to give Waterline a way to connect to Mongo if you don't have any Models already using Mongo) or use an existing Model and simply use `Model.native()` (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had thought of the second option but didn't consider it wise because sessions and models are handled by different adapters with different configurations. Also, I'd really like to avoid accessing sessions manually. Isn't there some standard procedure people apply for this? Because otherwise if you change your password from one session, you still stay authenticated in all your other active sessions.